# .htaccess throwing 404 with with letter P in RewriteRule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

This rule works perfectly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.[a-z0-9\-]{3,}\..*
RewriteRule ^t/(.*)$ /p.php?p=$1 [L]
```

This almost identical rule throws a 404:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.[a-z0-9\-]{3,}\..*
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /p.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Could there be some apache or DNS rule which is breaking this? I have the same .htaccess file on an older server and it works fine. The new server is CentOS7 with PHP7.

Comment: Do you have `p/` on the web server? If you don't then that's really the only logical reason the behavior you describe would happen.

Comment: Can you add `Options -MultiViews` before `RewriteEngine On` line and retest both rules.

Comment: I'm not sure how or why but this seems to have worked beautifully! Can you explain in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As evident from my comments that you have `MultiViews` option turned on by default.

You can turn it off by placing this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` module and makes Apache server match extensions of files. It is always better to turn it off while using `mod_rewrite` rules to avoid unexpected behavior like this.

e.g. `/file` is the URI and a file names `file.php` exists in your document root then Apache may find matching file and serve it instead of matching your rule.